# using a dll where path is in app.config

Tags: c#, dll

I am struggling with this and cannot find much on it at all.

My config file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity name="mydll"  culture="neutral"         publicKeyToken="3073773c0eff8935"/>
    <codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="FILE://C:/users/James/Desktop/mydll2.dll"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>
  </configuration>
```

I have inserted the location of my assembly and also the correct publickeytoken and version.

Obviously my assembly is not going to be in the bin folder and I would like to be able to change the location of the assembly when I like. I am stuck as to how to refer to this in my code. How can I call this assembly functions from my project?

I am assuming you need to add a reference to it somehow in to the project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For anybody else that stumbles across this...I have now done this...

There is a tutorial here...

https://web.archive.org/web/20070703223647/support.microsoft.com/kb/837908

By using the  tags in app.config the location of the assembly will be gotten at runtime.

All you should do is add a reference to the assembly and set 'assemblyIdentity name=' to the name of the reference added to the project.

Right click the reference -> properties, copy local = false;

Build your solution and you can update the app.config file with the location of the assembly.

Answer (score 1):

At run time you load the assmbly from the specific location

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("dllPath");
```

Comment: Thanks,although this would mean I need to change the source code of my project every time I would like to move the dll or rename it etc...I would like to avoid this and just set the location of the dll in the app.config file...

Is there a way to create an assembly object that reads the location from between the <codebase> tags in app.config that you know of?

Comment: Create one static class and load the assembly

Comment: This is a useful answer but it does not allow me to load an assembly from a location I choose without recompiling the app.